# I can't use django-tinymce upload picture,I installed django-filebrowser

Tags: django, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser

I have a question about django-tinymce upload picture.

django-filebrowser installed my project and work very well. I can use a FileBroseFiled upload files.

next I installed the django-tinymce to my project, used the tinmyce edit my content, everything is Ok except upload image from local. I can't open a browse page when click the Browse button, see the picture!:

the terminal return a error message:

```
"GET /tinymce/filebrowser/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71915
```

my setting file:

```
  # Django settings for max project.
# coding:utf-8
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'max_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/qin/django/max/uploads/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'aab%%d&_qxn8f0dd@v3q3_gdbn_joraege%q1tzl@uq6v1_3c#'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'max.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/qin/django/max/templates/'
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'max.grappelli',
    'max.filebrowser',
    'max.tinymce',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'max.article',
    'max.computer',
    'max.person',
)

#FILEBROWSE_DIRECTORY="/home/qin/Django/max/uploads"
FILEBROWSER_DEBUG=True

#the absolute path to the directory that holds your media-files.
FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT="/home/qin/django/max/uploads/"
#FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT=""

#URL that handlers the media served from MEDIA_ROOT.
FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL="http://192.168.213.132/uploads/"
FILEBROWSER_URL_FILEBROWSER_MEDIA="/admin_media/filebrowser/"
FILEBROWSER_PATH_FILEBROWSER_MEDIA=""
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY="uploads/"
FILEBROWSER_URL_TINYMCE='/admin_media/tiny_mce/'
FILEBROWSER_PATH_TINYMCE='/admin_media/tiny_mce/'


#the URL of the tinymce JavaScript file.
TINYMCE_JS_URL=(ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX+'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG={
    'plugins':"spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
    'theme':"advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup':True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels':10,
    'with':'100%',
    'height':'400',
    'verify_html':True,
    'accessibility_warnings':False,
 }
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT=('/home/qin/django/max/admin_medias/tiny_mce/')
TINYMCE_FILEBROWSER=True
```

Comment: when you open your page that tinymce is on are there are 404 messages that come up in the terminal?

Comment: yes, when I open the page(include the tinymce),the terminal is return the error message:

Comment: hi! did you go any further after that error? It seems to me that I have a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539957/small-problem-with-django-tinymce-and-django-filebrowser-integration