# small problem with django-tinymce and django-filebrowser integration

Tags: python, django, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser

I am trying to integrate django-tinymce with django-filebrowser for my
django admin site.
Everything (almost) works fine.

- `manage.py test filebrowser`, works ok
- `http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/` works, too

however when I press the `browse` button on the windows popup of
`insert/edit image` of tinymce button panel nothing happens.

in my firefox debug window I get an error like this (when pressing `browse`):

```
f is undefined
code: http://localhost:8000/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js
line: 11981
```

and on my dev-server output window I get a 500 error like this:

`GET /tinymce/filebrowser/ HTTP/1.1" 500` when admin page tries to load the  `tinymce_models.HTMLField()` text area.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

PS: I also use grappelli and this is my settings.py part that loads the apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
#... usual django standard apps.. #
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'tinymce',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'expedeat.dbadmin',
)
```

Comment: offtopic: imho django-filebrowser realy sucks vs http://elrte.org/elfinder/demo

Comment: thanks. elFinder looks great. What I want though, is a simple file browser/uploader to work with tinyMCE editor. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find the answer to my problem.

I had to modify the tinymce/views.py file like this:

```
fb_url = "%s://%s%s" % (request.is_secure() and 'https' or 'http',
    #request.get_host(), urlresolvers.reverse('filebrowser-index'))
    request.get_host(), urlresolvers.reverse('fb_browse'))
```

I found the answer in this post:
http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg100388.html

Comment: I have your problem too and go to tinymce/views.py but I could find any line like you had and modified it , what's your idea ?

Comment: No idea other than version changes. Please, go in the tinymce directory and try `grep -r "fb_url" .` to find where the above line lies.

Comment: I checked that but there wasn't any line like ```#request.get_host(), urlresolvers.reverse('filebrowser-index'))``` to modify it

Comment: It must be something with the versions. I know that this problem was resolved in the next iteration of tinymce. Do you have the latest versions of tinymce and filebrowser? What is the exact error message?